# GStreamer-CRITICAL **:: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed

Tags: 18.04, rhythmbox

Having the identical problem as this person under Ubuntu 18.04.
I'm able to read CDs using banshee and retrieve the metadata using picard, but rhythmbox fails to extract.

askubuntu.com/questions/888873/gstreamer-critical-gst-pad-link-full-assertion-gst-is-pad-sinkpad-faile

"It is not possible to extract Audio-CDs with Rhythmbox. When starting an Audio-CD extraction Rhythmbox prompts Error transferring track. Internal data flow error. Starting Rhythmbox in a terminal, the command line tells:

(rhythmbox:2854): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed."